# PyQt5 QTreeView.clear() AttributeError: 'QTreeView' object has no attribute 'clear'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

```
File "/.../.../........./app.py", line 64, in textchanged
    self.treeView.clear()

AttributeError: 'QTreeView' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

Any idea how to clear a QTreeView Widget? Google was no help

tried https://gist.github.com/tcrowson/8273931

```
import PySide
from PySide import QtGui

def clearQTreeWidget(tree):
    iterator = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree, QtGui.QTreeWidgetItemIterator.All)
    while iterator.value():
        iterator.value().takeChildren()
        iterator +=1
    i = tree.topLevelItemCount()
    while i > -1:
        tree.takeTopLevelItem(i)
        i -= 1
```

but in PyQt5:

```
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QTreeWidgetItemIterator'
```

Comment: The clear method is from QTreeWidget, not from QTreeView so you get the error. You don't have to clean the QTreeView but the QTreeView model, what model are you using?  Please provide  a [mre]

Comment: @pippo1980 Be more careful when copying from other people's code: that is for PySide (which corresponds to Qt4), Qt5 moved all widget-related classes from QtGui to QtWidgets. And, in any case, that's for QTreeWidget items: QTreeWidget is a higher level class based on QTreeView; please read more carefully what [item view convenience classes](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#item-view-convenience-classes) are, specifically, as the [QTreeWidget description explains](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html): "The QTreeWidget class provides a tree view that uses a **predefined tree model**."

Comment: It says: For PyQt/PySide. A simple function for clearing the contents of a QTreeWidget/QTreeView, since these classes lack convenient clear() or clearContents() methods. Takes a QTreeWidget or QTreeView object as an argument.

Comment: I'll try QrWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator in PyQt5 . Don't know exactly what a model is/ is for . I am just appendRow(qitems...) on a,first node to visualize Biopython PDB structure objects as a tree. Thanks for hints as always

Comment: Dont have Server access right now, I'll post a question about how to clear my qtreeview-model with the relevant code next week

Comment: I am using QStandardItemModel()

Comment: @pippo1980 Why don't you just use [model.clear()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#clear) or [model.setRowCount(0)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setRowCount)?

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro , its my first attempt with QTreeView and dont understand all PyQt either. Qt documentations is too high level for me , I'll try that

Comment: @musicamante model.clear() or self.model.setRowCount(0) did the job,  the https://gist.github.com/tcrowson/8273931  QtWidgetsQTreeWidgetItemIterator throws an   QTreeWidgetItemIterator(QTreeWidgetItemIterator): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QTreeView'

Comment: @pippo1980 Please read more carefully: as already said (and as the name suggests and the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html)), QTreeWidgetItemIterator is *only* for QTreeWidget, ***not*** QTreeView. If you want to recursively cycle through QTreeView elements, you must implement it with the model. I don't know who wrote that gist, but they are just wrong: 1. QTreeWidget has a `clear()` function since at least Qt4 (that's more than 10 years ago); 2. That function can only work with QTreeWidget, despite their claim that it would work with QTreeView.

Comment: @pippo1980 I know that the documentation might seem overwhelming, but item models are not a simple matter. If you want to use them, you **must** take your time to patiently study and understand the documentation, starting with the basic [model view introduction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) and going on with *all* the classes you're using, including inherited ones. Blindly copying code and trying things randomly will *not* help you unless you want to learn things in the hard way.

Comment: Yep I know, but wanted a fast method to show elements of a biopython PDB structure object in PyQt5, for the first 4 hours I even didnt notice that I was surfing code containg both QTreeView and other QTreeWidget thinking they were the same .....  ; - ) . Now I have both of them working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer is for all the people that helped me with their comments above:

1111.pdb :

```
ATOM      1  N   ASN A   1      -7.615   2.627   3.239  1.00  4.51           N  
ANISOU    1  N   ASN A   1      644    614    454    -45     26     52       N  
ATOM      2  CA  ASN A   1      -6.403   1.794   2.980  1.00  4.52           C  
ANISOU    2  CA  ASN A   1      638    558    520    -22    -10      3       C  
ATOM      3  C   ASN A   1      -5.154   2.381   3.598  1.00  4.76           C  
ANISOU    3  C   ASN A   1      618    625    565    -15     -6     -5       C  
ATOM      4  O   ASN A   1      -5.052   3.583   3.763  1.00  5.03           O  
ANISOU    4  O   ASN A   1      687    619    605     42    -54     -9       O  
ATOM      5  CB  ASN A   1      -6.219   1.595   1.484  1.00  4.79           C  
ANISOU    5  CB  ASN A   1      673    605    542     14      5    -27       C  
ATOM      6  CG  ASN A   1      -7.469   1.079   0.834  1.00  6.31           C  
ANISOU    6  CG  ASN A   1      755    877    767     26     17    -45       C  
ATOM      7  OD1 ASN A   1      -7.912  -0.028   1.124  1.00  5.83           O  
ANISOU    7  OD1 ASN A   1      854    753    610     60    -37   -119       O  
ATOM      8  ND2 ASN A   1      -8.079   1.901  -0.009  1.00  6.13           N  
ANISOU    8  ND2 ASN A   1      686    925    717     87     13      0       N  
ATOM      9  N   ASN A   2      -4.224   1.506   3.951  1.00  4.81           N  
ANISOU    9  N   ASN A   2      624    619    583      0     16     -5       N  
ATOM     10  CA  ASN A   2      -2.995   1.882   4.640  1.00  4.73           C  
ANISOU   10  CA  ASN A   2      604    608    584     -3     21      7       C  
ATOM     11  C   ASN A   2      -1.771   1.299   3.937  1.00  4.43           C  
ANISOU   11  C   ASN A   2      571    573    539     10     25      4       C  
ATOM     12  O   ASN A   2      -1.737   0.108   3.651  1.00  4.42           O  
ANISOU   12  O   ASN A   2      498    606    576     -8      6     34       O  
ATOM     13  CB  ASN A   2      -3.041   1.359   6.079  1.00  4.98           C  
ANISOU   13  CB  ASN A   2      638    630    626    -18     50     19       C  
ATOM     14  CG  ASN A   2      -1.845   1.784   6.884  1.00  5.61           C  
ANISOU   14  CG  ASN A   2      770    685    678    -10     17     29       C  
ATOM     15  OD1 ASN A   2      -1.609   2.986   7.034  1.00  7.46           O  
ANISOU   15  OD1 ASN A   2     1179    674    980    -44   -236     39       O  
ATOM     16  ND2 ASN A   2      -1.080   0.819   7.410  1.00  5.64           N  
ANISOU   16  ND2 ASN A   2      767    719    658    -36    -48     54       N  
ATOM     17  N   GLN A   3      -0.784   2.153   3.656  1.00  4.16           N  
ANISOU   17  N   GLN A   3      565    559    457     36      6      0       N  
ATOM     18  CA  GLN A   3       0.550   1.721   3.226  1.00  4.34           C  
ANISOU   18  CA  GLN A   3      567    556    526     10     21      8       C  
ATOM     19  C   GLN A   3       1.591   2.457   4.068  1.00  4.48           C  
ANISOU   19  C   GLN A   3      566    573    562     41      0      6       C  
ATOM     20  O   GLN A   3       1.617   3.677   4.085  1.00  4.56           O  
ANISOU   20  O   GLN A   3      576    576    580     16    -47     47       O  
ATOM     21  CB  GLN A   3       0.790   1.994   1.735  1.00  4.34           C  
ANISOU   21  CB  GLN A   3      533    574    541    -20     18     51       C  
ATOM     22  CG  GLN A   3       2.095   1.388   1.209  1.00  4.58           C  
ANISOU   22  CG  GLN A   3      676    524    540     32     30     10       C  
ATOM     23  CD  GLN A   3       2.524   1.951  -0.124  1.00  4.63           C  
ANISOU   23  CD  GLN A   3      680    546    532    -56      7     -3       C  
ATOM     24  OE1 GLN A   3       2.751   3.154  -0.250  1.00  4.86           O  
ANISOU   24  OE1 GLN A   3      741    508    598    -99     97    108       O  
ATOM     25  NE2 GLN A   3       2.670   1.085  -1.122  1.00  3.96           N  
ANISOU   25  NE2 GLN A   3      549    403    554     59    -29    -44       N  
ATOM     26  N   GLN A   4       2.425   1.709   4.783  1.00  4.51           N  
ANISOU   26  N   GLN A   4      570    573    572     26      0      4       N  
ATOM     27  CA  GLN A   4       3.503   2.295   5.567  1.00  5.00           C  
ANISOU   27  CA  GLN A   4      616    655    629      7    -13     19       C  
ATOM     28  C   GLN A   4       4.824   1.700   5.121  1.00  4.74           C  
ANISOU   28  C   GLN A   4      566    615    619     10    -23     16       C  
ATOM     29  O   GLN A   4       4.977   0.485   5.042  1.00  4.74           O  
ANISOU   29  O   GLN A   4      499    623    680     34    -69     61       O  
ATOM     30  CB  GLN A   4       3.263   2.101   7.063  1.00  5.31           C  
ANISOU   30  CB  GLN A   4      638    704    674     -1    -17     35       C  
ATOM     31  CG  GLN A   4       2.128   2.959   7.602  1.00  6.23           C  
ANISOU   31  CG  GLN A   4      784    793    792    -13     12     41       C  
ATOM     32  CD  GLN A   4       1.734   2.581   9.002  1.00  6.26           C  
ANISOU   32  CD  GLN A   4      816    844    719    -70    -74    -50       C  
ATOM     33  OE1 GLN A   4       1.144   1.526   9.223  1.00  7.59           O  
ANISOU   33  OE1 GLN A   4      989   1052    841   -241    -67     25       O  
ATOM     34  NE2 GLN A   4       2.088   3.427   9.976  1.00  8.64           N  
ANISOU   34  NE2 GLN A   4     1402   1172    710    -95    -36   -172       N  
ATOM     35  N   ASN A   5       5.758   2.597   4.821  1.00  5.19           N  
ANISOU   35  N   ASN A   5      596    702    673    -16      8     23       N  
ATOM     36  CA  ASN A   5       7.061   2.275   4.262  1.00  5.29           C  
ANISOU   36  CA  ASN A   5      642    709    660     11     -1      8       C  
ATOM     37  C   ASN A   5       8.114   2.789   5.215  1.00  5.89           C  
ANISOU   37  C   ASN A   5      700    750    788    -28     -4    -18       C  
ATOM     38  O   ASN A   5       8.370   3.981   5.260  1.00  6.26           O  
ANISOU   38  O   ASN A   5      765    718    897    -40    -47     31       O  
ATOM     39  CB  ASN A   5       7.185   2.937   2.893  1.00  5.44           C  
ANISOU   39  CB  ASN A   5      620    819    628     18     -1     23       C  
ATOM     40  CG  ASN A   5       6.036   2.570   1.974  1.00  4.77           C  
ANISOU   40  CG  ASN A   5      581    600    633     -7     71    -35       C  
ATOM     41  OD1 ASN A   5       5.922   1.414   1.558  1.00  4.98           O  
ANISOU   41  OD1 ASN A   5      758    486    648     56    -38    -81       O  
ATOM     42  ND2 ASN A   5       5.157   3.538   1.679  1.00  4.95           N  
ANISOU   42  ND2 ASN A   5      531    675    676   -141     28     79       N  
ATOM     43  N   TYR A   6       8.692   1.895   6.001  1.00  5.71           N  
ANISOU   43  N   TYR A   6      720    684    764    -31     -6    -29       N  
ATOM     44  CA  TYR A   6       9.522   2.304   7.140  1.00  6.06           C  
ANISOU   44  CA  TYR A   6      787    751    763    -21      1    -18       C  
ATOM     45  C   TYR A   6      10.972   2.565   6.754  1.00  6.79           C  
ANISOU   45  C   TYR A   6      852    866    863     -4    -20    -14       C  
ATOM     46  O   TYR A   6      11.344   2.407   5.590  1.00  6.49           O  
ANISOU   46  O   TYR A   6      864    773    829      5     17     59       O  
ATOM     47  CB  TYR A   6       9.432   1.277   8.273  1.00  6.25           C  
ANISOU   47  CB  TYR A   6      771    825    777     -9      1     -3       C  
ATOM     48  CG  TYR A   6       8.034   1.157   8.838  1.00  6.51           C  
ANISOU   48  CG  TYR A   6      872    761    840    -24     50     29       C  
ATOM     49  CD1 TYR A   6       7.124   0.253   8.307  1.00  7.04           C  
ANISOU   49  CD1 TYR A   6      893    876    905    -54     60      0       C  
ATOM     50  CD2 TYR A   6       7.618   1.964   9.891  1.00  6.57           C  
ANISOU   50  CD2 TYR A   6      816    839    841    -36    -22     -8       C  
ATOM     51  CE1 TYR A   6       5.838   0.139   8.824  1.00  7.41           C  
ANISOU   51  CE1 TYR A   6      891    961    963    -52    -26    -14       C  
ATOM     52  CE2 TYR A   6       6.330   1.864  10.407  1.00  7.41           C  
ANISOU   52  CE2 TYR A   6      928   1009    877    -29     30    -28       C  
ATOM     53  CZ  TYR A   6       5.451   0.942   9.879  1.00  7.24           C  
ANISOU   53  CZ  TYR A   6      823   1006    922     -7     36     18       C  
ATOM     54  OH  TYR A   6       4.177   0.856  10.381  1.00  8.39           O  
ANISOU   54  OH  TYR A   6      988   1099   1102    -75     51     70       O  
ATOM     55  OXT TYR A   6      11.788   2.976   7.592  1.00  8.07           O  
ANISOU   55  OXT TYR A   6      968   1126    971    -28    -50     10       O  
TER      56      TYR A   6                                                      
HETATM   57 ZN    ZN A   7      13.281   2.891   5.326  1.00  6.49          ZN  
ANISOU   57 ZN    ZN A   7      784    821    860    -54     33     -6      ZN  
HETATM   58  C   ACY A  10      14.386   5.403   6.406  1.00  6.91           C  
ANISOU   58  C   ACY A  10      850    912    865    -52    -40     25       C  
HETATM   59  O   ACY A  10      14.546   6.633   6.397  1.00  6.40           O  
ANISOU   59  O   ACY A  10      765    812    853     78    -65    147       O  
HETATM   60  OXT ACY A  10      13.622   4.803   5.620  1.00  6.13           O  
ANISOU   60  OXT ACY A  10      798    706    827   -127      2    -40       O  
HETATM   61  CH3 ACY A  10      15.156   4.626   7.437  1.00  7.00           C  
ANISOU   61  CH3 ACY A  10      882    946    832    -65    -43      6       C  
HETATM   62  O   HOH A   8     -10.505   1.596   3.027  1.00  5.62           O  
ANISOU   62  O   HOH A   8      682    921    531     -3     99    -98       O  
HETATM   63  O   HOH A   9     -10.556   4.008   1.574  1.00  5.67           O  
ANISOU   63  O   HOH A   9      664    744    747     78    -92    -79       O  
HETATM   64  O   HOH A  11      12.427   4.356   9.859  1.00 15.37           O  
ANISOU   64  O   HOH A  11     1819   2319   1702   -118      1      0       O  
HETATM   65  O   HOH A  12      13.627   6.646   9.636  1.00 25.87           O  
ANISOU   65  O   HOH A  12     3544   3345   2941   -113    -31    -55       O  
HETATM   66  O   HOH A  13       0.421   0.597  11.913  1.00 37.06           O  
ANISOU   66  O   HOH A  13     4669   4811   4602     -8    -10    -69       O  
HETATM   67  O   HOH A  14      -1.801  -0.217  12.498  1.00 39.09           O  
ANISOU   67  O   HOH A  14     4948   5054   4851    -31     83      1       O  
HETATM   68  O   HOH A  15      -1.057   2.545  11.391  1.00 49.99           O  
ANISOU   68  O   HOH A  15     6356   6344   6294    -19     13    -16       O  
CONECT   46   57                                                                
CONECT   55   57                                                                
CONECT   57   46   55   60                                                      
CONECT   58   59   60   61                                                      
CONECT   59   58                                                                
CONECT   60   57   58                                                           
CONECT   61   58                                                                
MASTER      253    0    2    0    0    0    2    6   67    1    7    1          
END
```

mainwin4.py   :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MyApp(object):
    def setupUi(self, MyApp):
        MyApp.setObjectName("MyApp")
        MyApp.resize(786, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MyApp)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 70, 301, 41))
        self.lineEdit_input.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_input.setObjectName("lineEdit_input")
        self.pushButton_input = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 70, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setItalic(False)
        self.pushButton_input.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_input.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_input.setObjectName("pushButton_input")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 151, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setItalic(False)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 170, 331, 391))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "1")
        self.treeWidget.header().setVisible(True)
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 170, 331, 391))
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        self.treeView.header().setVisible(True)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 140, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MyApp.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MyApp)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyApp)

    def retranslateUi(self, MyApp):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MyApp.setWindowTitle(_translate("MyApp", "MyApp"))
        self.pushButton_input.setText(_translate("MyApp", "load"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MyApp", "insert PDB code"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MyApp", "        QTreeView"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MyApp", "        QTreeWidget"))
```

main.py :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, \
                            QTreeWidgetItem
                            
from PyQt5 import  QtGui, QtWidgets

from mainwin4 import Ui_MyApp

from Bio.PDB import PDBParser



class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MyApp):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.lineEdit_input.setMaxLength(4)
        self.lineEdit_input.setPlaceholderText("   4 characters PDB entry code")
        self.lineEdit_input.textChanged.connect(self.textchanged)
        
        self.pushButton_input.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_input.clicked.connect(self.load_pdb)
        self.pushButton_input.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s " % '#fa6555') 
        
        
        self.model = None
        self.treeView.hide()
        # self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
        
        self.treeWidget.hide()
        
    
    def textchanged(self):
        
        if len(self.lineEdit_input.text()) == 4:
            self.pushButton_input.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s " % '#9de650') 
            self.pushButton_input.setEnabled(True)
            self.treeView.show()
            
            self.treeWidget.show()
        
        else:
            self.pushButton_input.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s " % '#fa6555') 
            self.pushButton_input.setEnabled(False)
            
                        
            # TO CLEAR QTreeView
            
            if self.model != None : 
                # self.model.clear()       # works
                self.model.setRowCount(0)  # works 
                
            
            # TO CLEAR QTreeWidget
            # self.treeWidget.clear()   # works
            
            self.clearQTreeWidget(self.treeWidget) # works
            
            
            self.treeView.hide()
            
            self.treeWidget.hide()
        
    def load_pdb(self):
        
        self.pushButton_input.setEnabled(False)

        self. parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1, QUIET=1)
        
        try:
            print(self.lineEdit_input.text()+'.pdb')
            
            self.structure = self.parser.get_structure(self.lineEdit_input.text(), self.lineEdit_input.text()+'.pdb')
            
            print('load')
            
            # self.read_bfact()
            
            self.create_tree()
        
                
        except:
                
                self.msg = QMessageBox(self)
                self.msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
                self.msg.setText("Error")
                self.msg.setInformativeText('no PDB found')
                self.msg.setDetailedText("details")
                self.msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
                self.msg.show()
                self.lineEdit_input.setText('')
            
            
    
    def create_tree(self):
        
        
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        
        self.rootNode = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        
        self.stru = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.structure.id)
        
        
        self.rootNode.appendRow(self.stru)
        
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        
        # self.treeView.expandAll()
        
        for model in self.structure:
            
            self.mod = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(model.id+1))
            self.stru.appendRow(self.mod)
        
        
            for chain in model:
                
                self.cha = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(chain.id))
                self.mod.appendRow(self.cha)
                
                
                for residue in chain:
                    
                    self.res = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(residue.get_resname()))
                    self.cha.appendRow(self.res)
                    
                    for atom in residue:
                        
                        self.ato = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(atom.id +' '+ str(atom.get_serial_number())))  
                        self.res.appendRow(self.ato)
          
        
        # self.treeView.expandAll()
            
        self.items = []
        
        self.struct = QTreeWidgetItem([str(self.structure.id)])
        
        
        for model in self.structure:
            
            item = QTreeWidgetItem([str(model.id+1)])
            
            self.struct.addChild(item)
            
            
            for chain in model:
                
                child = QTreeWidgetItem([str(chain.id)])
                
                item.addChild(child)
                
                for residue in chain:
                    
                    child2 = QTreeWidgetItem([str(residue.get_resname())])
                    
                    child.addChild(child2)
                    
                    for atom in residue:
                        
                        child3 = QTreeWidgetItem([str(atom.id +' '+ str(atom.get_serial_number()))])
                        
                        child2.addChild(child3)
                        
        self.items.append(self.struct)
                
        self.treeWidget.insertTopLevelItems(0, self.items)  
        
        # self.treeWidget.expandAll()
    
    

    def clearQTreeWidget(self, tree):
        iterator = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree, QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator.All)
        while iterator.value():
            iterator.value().takeChildren()
            iterator +=1
        i = tree.topLevelItemCount()
        while i > -1:
            tree.takeTopLevelItem(i)
            i -= 1  


            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyApp()
    myapp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

I tried to create a visualization of PDB object with both `QTreeView` and `QTreeWidget` ,  script load a pdb file in its same directory (insert 1111 if file is called 1111.pdb) . Then visualize its structure pushing LOAD button, if the PDB entry code into input window is canceled  the two visualization trees are erased with this code:

```
            # TO CLEAR QTreeView
            
            if self.model != None : 
                # self.model.clear()       # works
                self.model.setRowCount(0)  # works 
                
            
            # TO CLEAR QTreeWidget
            # self.treeWidget.clear()   # works
            
            self.clearQTreeWidget(self.treeWidget) # works
```

Not sure this is the best way to use `QTreeView` and `QTreeWidget`

but at least I got a grasp on how to clear them